# Non-type template parameter pack for class data member pointer can't compile with gcc

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, auto, template-argument-deduction

I try to write a code with c++17 `auto` **non-type template parameter pack** for class data member pointer, but the following code clang will compile and gcc will not, [you can see godbolt for error message](https://godbolt.org/z/bb5ugq), can somebody tell me which one should I believe since I can't figure out why gcc reject this.

Thanks for you help.

```
template <
    typename B,
    template <auto B::*...> typename Wrapper, 
    auto B::*... Args
>
void f(Wrapper<Args...>) {}

template <auto... Args> struct Wrapper {};
struct A { int i; float f; };

// gcc error: unable to deduce 'auto B::*' from '&A::i'
f(Wrapper<&A::i, &A::f>{});
```

I know that if change `<auto B::*...>` to `<auto...>` then both can compile, but I want know **why** gcc couldn't deduce correct type since the following **non-auto** template parameter get same situation: gcc can't compile and clang can:

```
template <
    typename B,
    typename... MT,
    template <MT B::*...> class Wrapper, 
    MT B::*... Args
>
void f(Wrapper<Args...>) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
template <
    template <auto ...> typename Wrapper, 
    auto ... Args
>
void f(Wrapper<Args...>) {}
```

`auto` is an alternative for `B::*`; so you should use `auto` **or** `B::*`, not both.

Comment: @康桓瑋 - to be honest, I don't know; your new `f()` seems me correct but I suspect the problem is in the `Wrapper` struct that is still written with `auto`; but I don't know how to write `Wrapper`, in a simple way, without `auto`. The question, at this point, should be "who's right between c++ and clang++?"

Comment: @康桓瑋 - Thinking a little about it, I suspect it's a g++ bug. But not sure. I've reproduced it in a little simpler example. Do you mind if I propose it as another question for language layers?